# My iPad keep automatically adding a dictionary even when I delete them repeatedly

Tags: ipad, dictionary, ipados, look-up

I am using my `iPad Mini` (6th generation: iOS `15.0.2`) to read articles online. I like the `look up` function very much. However, I realized that somehow my iPad keeps randomly adding a Spanish dictionary. This may have started once I tried to install the Spanish dictionary awhile back. After that, even after I delete the Spanish dictionary, I still keep seeing the Spanish dictionary entry lookup.

This is quite annoying because I no longer need the Spanish dictionary and I just want to see an English dictionary.

I would appreciate it if I could learn why dictionaries that I delete will come back as installed dictionaries.

Comment: Try updating to iOS 15.1 and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @anonymous! I updated all of my devices to iOS 15.1 and a couple of days later (which is today), I found that one of them automatically reinstalled the Spanish dictionary again.